# pdfMake pageBreakBefore feature is not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pdfmake

I am trying to concatenate multiple pdf files to a content variable.   However I want each pdf content to be on a new page,  but pdfmake.js just concatenate each content right after the other.   I have added 'pageBreakBefore' function right after my content but it still doesn't work.   Is there a way to make each content to be on separate page.   (I am using jpdmake.js 1.60).   Thanks!

Below is my code:

```
        let content = [];
        content = this.getContent(checkedOrders, selectedLabOrders);
        this.docDefinition = {
                      info: {
                        title: 'Title',
                        subject: 'labOrder-' 
                      },
                      pageSize: 'LETTER',
                      pageOrientation: 'landscape',
                      pageMargins: [40, 30, 40, 30],
        
                      content: content,
                      pageBreakBefore: function(currentNode, followingNodesOnPage, nodesOnNextPage, previousNodesOnPage) {
                        return currentNode.headlineLevel === 1 && followingNodesOnPage.length === 0;
                      },
                      unbreakable: true,
                      styles: {
                        titleHeader: {
                          fontSize: 16,
                          bold: true,
                          margin: [0, 10, 0, 0],
                        },
                        tableHeader: {
                          bold: true,
                          fontSize: 13,
                          color: 'black'
                        }
                      },
                      defaultStyle: {
                        fontSize: 9,
                        lineHeight: .9
                      }
                    };
```

[image]

Comment: which pdf maker are you using ? `jpdmake.js 1.60` I am not getting this

Comment: Holy cow!  pageBreak: 'after'  works like a charm.   Thanks GRD!

Comment: Hi GRD.   I was trying to buy you coffee but it requires you phone number.